# drill-jdbc vs dril-jdbc-all jar

Tags: apache-drill

There are two JDBC drivers for apache-drill: `drill-jdbc` & `drill-jdbc-all`

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using `drill-jdbc` and things are working fine.

But according to drill's [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/#getting-the-drill-jdbc-driver) for JDBC, driver is located at:

```
 <drill_installation_directory>/jars/jdbc-driver/drill-jdbc-all-<version>.jar
```

Means `drill-jdbc-all` should be used.

I got confused between these jars. **What is the difference in these two jars?**

Comment: There are some problems that you might now, or soon, be able to work around. Please see  
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3502

Comment: @catpaws any difference functionality wise in these two jars?

Comment: The drill-jdbc doesn't package dependencies. The drill-jdbc-all-<version>.jar packages all the dependencies, and if you have a conflicting jar on your path, it can cause a problem.

Comment: @catpaws so there is no difference besides **package dependencies**. Right?

Comment: Right, that's what a Drill dev and a qa guy said.

Comment: @catpaws add this as an answer so that it would help others if they have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There differences between drill-jdbc & drill-jdbc-all is that the drill-jdbc doesn't package dependencies. There are no differences between package dependencies. The drill-jdbc-all-.jar packages all the dependencies, and if you have a conflicting jar on your path, it can cause a problem.