# Java Client Jar for Apache Drill

Tags: apache, web-services, apache-drill, java-client

I have a machine on which I am storing some data in the form of json or csv.
and on same machine `Apache Drill` is also running.
I can access the `Apache Drill` using web console on different machine. and also can execute the sql query on the file that store on the machine where `Apache Drill` is running.
Now I want to create a program that can execute sql query as I am doing on web browser in web console of `Apache Drill`.

Can anyone know about the jar like **webhdfs-java-client-0.0.2.jar** used for `Hadoop hdfs`?

I am looking for such a **`java client`** jar for `Apache Drill`.

Comment: which drill version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using **drill-jdbc driver**. Check Drill's [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/).

If you are using maven, add [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.drill.exec/drill-jdbc/1.4.0) dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample code (*assuming drill running on xx.xx.xx.xx*):

```
Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver");

Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:drillbit=xx.xx.xx.xx");
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(<your SQL query>);
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

If you want zookeeper to start drill automatically, use:

```
Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:zk=xx.xx.xx.xx");
```

Note: Here xx.xx.xx.xx can be IP address or host name.

**Edit:** Check my [github project](https://github.com/devender-yadav/DrillJDBC) for more details.

Comment: Also, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921835/drill-jdbc-vs-dril-jdbc-all-jar